# How to change format of the phone number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At this time, the format is the next phone

```
123-123-1123
```

I want to have the next form:

```
(123)456-7890
```

How can I change the format to whatever shape that I want?

```
<input class="" type="text" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" maxlength="10" placeholder="1234567890">
```

```js
$("#primary_phone").blur(function() {
    text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
    $(this).val(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/2864/

Comment: To avoid headaches, use a jQuery input masking plugin:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var phone = "123-123-1123";
    var newPhone = "(" + phone.replace("-", ")");
    alert(newPhone);
```

Answer (score 1):

The transformation is taken care of by the regular expression which forms the first argument of the text `.replace()` function, and where the output is the second argument.  Changing the format of the second argument is all that's needed here.

```
$("#primary_phone").blur(function() {
  text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1)$2-$3");
  $(this).val(text);
});
//=> (123)456-7890
```

Hope that helps.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#primary_phone" ).blur(function() {
            text = $(this).val().replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, '($1)$2-$3');
        $(this).val(text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8sv89tg/